# secure password token libraries

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, apache

I am looking to generate some random token  in Java for my temporary password which should contain all the alpha numeric characters and special characters. So, I have implemented it as:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
String str=new BigInteger(500, random).toString(32);
System.out.println(str);
```

Now my boss wants me to find a library or so to generate more better secure token containing special characters and so.... How can I do it in java?? Please help

Comment: Any reason for the `c#` tag?

Comment: No reason ... just with an assumption "a person who knows c# would know JAVA" :P correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Based on the assumption that knowledge of "C# means Java" person knowing of existence `SecureRandom` should be easily map sequence of bytes to sequence of characters (picking 256 characters from Unicode range is skill that should not require any additional knowledge)

Comment: Alright ... thanks for proving me wrong :).... Any suggestion regarding the answer to my solution ?